# Camunda webapp doesn't show tasks via LDAP user

Tags: camunda

I am using tomcat base camunda engine and added LDAP plugin. I have defined "administratorUserName" property in bpm-platform.xml

I am able to login and view all processes and all 3 screens i.e. cockpit, admin panel and tasklist.

But tasklist panel is not showing any tasks. It was working fine without LDAP plugin! Also I can fetch all tasks using rest api, so tasks are definitely present.

Any idea on what might have gone wrong? I have attached few screenshots for clarity.

[image: task process view]

[image: task authorization]

[image: task list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Camunda tasklist screen doesn't show tasks if you don't have any filter. If you click on "Add a simple filter" link, it will automatically create an empty filter listing all tasks or you can create your own customized filter by clicking "Create a filter +" link.